Can I enter Gibraltar being Ukrainian citizen to be received BRP By Scotland Supersponsor Visa on Homes for Ukraine scheme?
Can I enter Gibraltar being Ukrainian citizen to be received BRP By Scotland Supersponsor Visa on Homes for Ukraine scheme?
I am Ukrainian Citizen with UK Homes for Ukraine Scotland Government Supersponsor Visa and I expect to receive BRP soon

Would you be entering Gibraltar by air, sea, or land?

assume by car on land, but does this matter?

It would matter to the extent that if you're in Spain you (presumably) are legally in the Schengen area, whereas if you enter by sea or air then that isn't necessarily the case.  I don't know whether that is decisive in any event, so maybe it does not matter.

Yes. According to the Gibraltar Borders & Coastguard Agency, the following are visa-exempt:

Persons holding EU residence as a family member of an EU national.

UK Biometric Residence permits or a UK multiple entry visa issued for 6 months or more. Entry into Gibraltar is at the discretion of the immigration officer. Holding UK residence does not entitle the person to work, receive public benefits and/or reside in Gibraltar.

Persons who hold indefinite leave to remain in the UK (or Crown Dependencies) and persons who hold UK certificates of entitlement to the right of abode and have not been absent from the UK for more than 2 years. Entry into Gibraltar is at the discretion of the immigration officer. Holding indefinite leave in the UK does not provide the person with rights to work, receive public benefits and/or reside in Gibraltar.


